# Working with nested .NET enums in AX 2009

Tags: .net, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a DLL with a class `TestService.TestServiceWebClient`.
It's constructor has two parameters, one of type `string`, and the other one is of type `TestService.TestServiceWebClient.MODE` which is an enum.

In C#, I use this easily with the code below.

```
string secret;
secret = "asdfasdf";

TestService.TestServiceWebClient test = new TestService.TestServiceWebClient(secret, TestService.TestServiceWebClient.MODE.TEST);

test.setGroupForCustomer("test@foo.com", "12345", "TestService.TestServiceWebClient.CUST_GROUPS.MILITARY);
```

In AX, I'm having some trouble. I know the DLL is referenced properly because I see the parameters when I create an instance of the class, but I'm getting errors such as

> The class TestService does not contain this function

when I use the keyword `new`:

```
TestService test;
;
test = new TestService.TestServiceWebClient(secret, "");
```

I've also tried...

```
TestService.TestServiceWebClient test;
;
test = new TestService.TestServiceWebClient(secret, "");
```

That second argument is NOT a `string`, so when I try to add an enum, I get

> enumeration doesn't exist...

```
TestService test;
;
test = new TestService.TestServiceWebClient(secret, TestService.TestServiceWebClient.MODE::TEST);
```

Do I need an enum created in AX that would map to the enums from my DLL?

C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace ProductService
{
    public class TestWebClient
    {
        public enum CUST_GROUPS
        {
            NOT_LOGGED_IN,
            GENERAL,
            WHOLESALE,
            RETAILER,
            TEST_REVIEWS,
            COTM_DISCOUNT,
            MILITARY,
            FIRST_RESPONDER
        };

        public enum MODE
        {
            DEV,
            TEST,
            PROD
        }
        public static int COTM_GROUP_ID = 5;
        public static int GENERAL_GROUP_ID = 1;

        private string presharedSecret;

        private string BASE_URL;

        private static string destinationPathPut = "/path";
        private static string destinationPathGet = "/pathgroup";
        public TestWebClient(String presharedSecret, MODE mode)
        {
            this.presharedSecret = presharedSecret;
            switch (mode)
            {
                case MODE.DEV:
                    BASE_URL = "http://dev";
                    break;
                case MODE.TEST:
                    BASE_URL = "http://test";
                    break;
                case MODE.PROD:
                    BASE_URL = "https://prod";
                    break;
            }
        }

        public bool setGroupForCustomer(string customerEmail, string customerId, CUST_GROUPS selectedGroup)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            try
            {
                NameValueCollection requestParams = new NameValueCollection();
                requestParams.Add("customer_id", customerId);
                requestParams.Add("email", customerEmail);
                requestParams.Add("group_id", ((int)selectedGroup).ToString());
                requestParams.Add("signature", Util.sha1Hash(customerId.ToString() + ((int)selectedGroup).ToString() + customerEmail + presharedSecret));
                byte[] response = client.UploadValues(BASE_URL + "/" + destinationPathPut,
                    requestParams
                );
                string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                client.Dispose();
            }
            return true;
        }

        public bool isInGroup(string customerEmail, string customerId, CUST_GROUPS selectedGroup)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            NameValueCollection requestParams = new NameValueCollection();
            requestParams.Add("customer_id", customerId);
            requestParams.Add("email", customerEmail);
            requestParams.Add("group_id", ((int)selectedGroup).ToString());
            requestParams.Add("signature", Util.sha1Hash(customerId.ToString() + ((int)selectedGroup).ToString() + customerEmail + presharedSecret));
            byte[] response = client.UploadValues(BASE_URL + "/" + destinationPathGet,
                 requestParams
            );
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
            client.Dispose();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
            return result.Equals("true");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Working with nested .NET enums in DynamicsAX 2009 is a bit awful - if you have control over the source of your assembly and you can change it without affecting other users I would suggest to move it up to the same level as your class. Another approach would be to write a proxy method or class in order to do the object construction for you.

That being said, there is a way to work with them using reflection.
The following should give you an idea how to do it based on the framework enum `System.Environment.SpecialFolder` which is also nested.

```
static void NestedEnumDemo1(Args _args)
{
    System.Type classType;
    System.Type enumType;
    System.Enum enumValue;
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo;
    System.Object[] methodArgs;
    System.String specialFolderPath;
    str msg;
    ;

    classType = System.Type::GetType('System.Environment');
    enumType = System.Type::GetType('System.Environment+SpecialFolder');
    enumValue = System.Enum::Parse(enumType, 'System');
    methodInfo = classType.GetMethod('GetFolderPath');
    methodArgs = new System.Object[1]();
    methodArgs.SetValue(enumValue, 0);
    specialFolderPath = methodInfo.Invoke(null, methodArgs);
    msg = specialFolderPath;
    info(msg);
}
```

So for your case it may look similar to this, although I can't test it as I haven't your assembly but it should at least point you into the right direction:

```
static void NestedEnumDemo2(Args _args)
{
    System.Type classType;
    System.Type enumType;
    System.Enum enumValue;

    System.Type[] constructorParmTypes;
    System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo constructorInfo;

    System.String secret;
    System.Object[] constructorArgs;
    System.Object object;
    TestService.TestServiceWebClient test;
    ;

    classType = System.Type::GetType('TestService.TestServiceWebClient');
    enumType = System.Type::GetType('TestService.TestServiceWebClient+MODE');
    enumValue = System.Enum::Parse(enumType, 'TEST');

    constructorParmTypes = new System.Type[2]();
    constructorParmTypes.SetValue(System.Type::GetType('System.String'), 0);
    constructorParmTypes.SetValue(enumType, 1);
    constructorInfo = classType.GetConstructor(constructorParmTypes);

    secret = 'xxxxx';
    constructorArgs = new System.Object[2]();
    constructorArgs.SetValue(secret, 0);
    constructorArgs.SetValue(enumValue, 1);
    object = constructorInfo.Invoke(constructorArgs);
    test = object;
    // ...
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for that. Our "VAR" has some code similar to this. I'll try yours out.

Comment: Did you have a chance to look at it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay... I got pulled off onto other projects. I'm back on this today.

Comment: I updated my question with C# code. When I use this; enumType = System.Type::GetType('ProductService.TestWebClient+MODE'); It prints 'Class'. Shouldn't it be 'Enum'? Also, when I add, enumValue = System.Enum::Parse(enumType, 'TEST'); I get "ClrObject static method invocation error."

Comment: I'm not having much success... Maybe I should just change the enums to strings to that I can pass them from AX. @DAXaholic